# jQuery change only text but not affect element in span

Tags: jquery, laravel

In laravel project, blade file.
I have following line.

```
 <td><span id="date"> {{ $data->p_date}}<input type="text" class="datepic" id="custom_datepicker{{$payment->p_id}}"  data-multiselect = "{{count(explode(',', $data->p_date))}}" name="book_date[]"  placeholder="MONTH/DAY/YEAR" value="{{$data->p_date}}" style="display: flex; float: right;"/></span></td>
```

As you can see, in side  element, there is span text and also there is  element.
I want only change the text of  but not change the  block.
when I used this
`$("#date").text('')`,
It all removed including  element.
I want only remove the  text when I click a button.
Please give me a suggestion.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no native way to do this, one workaround is this.

```js
        var span = $('#date');
        var input = span.find('input');
        span.text('New Text');
        span.append(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are wrapping the input element with your span tag, try something like this

```
<td><span id="date"> {{ $data->p_date}}</span><input type="text" class="datepic" id="custom_datepicker{{$payment->p_id}}"  data-multiselect = "{{count(explode(',', $data->p_date))}}" name="book_date[]"  placeholder="MONTH/DAY/YEAR" value="{{$data->p_date}}" style="display: flex; float: right;"/></td>
```

then try

```
$("#date").text('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would not do that straight from the server side.

If you just want to retain the single element (or input elements), then use the [`.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/) method like so:

```
$('#date').html(function() {
    return $(this).find('input');
});
```

```js
$('#date').html(function() {
    return $(this).find('input');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="date">whatever text<input type="text" class="datepic" style="display: flex; float: right;"/>Or other text here<anotherElement>Retain this too</anotherElement></span>
```

To just remove text nodes and retain everything else combine the [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) method with the [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) method this way:

```
$('#date').html(function() {
    return $(this).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType !== 3;
    });
});
```

```js
$('#date').html(function() {
    return $(this).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType !== 3;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="date">whatever text<input type="text" class="datepic" style="display: flex; float: right;"/>Or other text here<anotherElement>Retain this too</anotherElement></span>
```